# How to run socket.io after user enter the port number in express?

Tags: express, socket.io

I want to run socket.io after user enter number of port in the express
if user doesn't enter number start at default port
else start at user port number.
But i can't find the solution.

I wrote this , but not working.

```
router.get("/run", (req, res, next) => {
      let IO = socketIo.listen();
    
      IO.on("connection", (client) => {
        console.log("On");
        console.log(client.handshake.query);
      });

      next();

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
let socketPort = 3000;
const io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', client => { /* your code */ });

router.get("/run", (req,res)=>{
    socketPort = req.query.port || socketPort
    io.listen(Number(socketPort))
})
```

Hope this helps! feel free to comment if you are stuck with any errors.

Comment: thank you, but still have problem with client,
I wrote this code in the express router and i want to use client in other middleware but i cant access.
Do you how to fix that ?

Comment: At that time, create a variable for the client globally... and assign the client as soon as you get it.
And access the variable when you need it in middleware.